# how to modify one section from another

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to figure out how to modify some properties of a section (such as text color or visibility) when clicking one element of a grid that has multiple colors (see image_1). I have already done the function to get the color of the clicked element but now I want to send this color value to the other section of the page (which has its own id).

when i use getElementById() function it returns null and i do not know how to solve it...

[IMAGE_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb5gI.png)

```
function getColor(cell) {
var actual = document.getElementById(cell.id);
    
    color = actual.style.background;
    idWrap = actual.id.substr(0,3);
    alert("#"+idWrap);
        var element = document.getElementById("#"+idWrap)
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Preferribly in the form of a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Also if `document.getElementById` returns `null` then either the element you're looking for is not on the page or `cell.id` does not contain the value you expect it to contain.

Comment: Solved.. I had an issue in the wordpress page related with the ids... thanks anywaw :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing the `#` to the `document.getElementById(...)` function. Simply remove it and it should work:

```js
var element = document.getElementById(idWrap)
```

Comment: Or he can use `var element = document.querySelector("#"+idWrap)`

Comment: thanks for helping me but i tried both options and i keep obtaining a null value. In the case of getElementById, it returns null if it does not find the id. so I am thinking that maybe the getElementById is looking inside the first container (where the grid is ) and not in the whole page and so the idWrap value cannot be found.

Comment: solved... I had an issue in the wordpress page related with the ids...  document.getElementById(...) solution works perfectly :)